# Customise apache.conf - set Timeout

Tags: apache, docker, mod-wsgi

I'm deploying a Flask web service in a container using Apache and mod_wsgi. Is there a way to control the Apache timeout parameter (in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`) in the mod_wsgi configuration file? I note that when the container gets built this Apache parameter is set to the default 5 minutes, but I need this to be set to 6 hours to handle large/long-running POST requests.

I understand that you can override Apache settings by using `apachectl start -c <directive setting>`, but I need the `Timeout` parameter to be set explicitly in the `apache.conf` file, before Apache starts.

Comment: The ``Timeout`` setting is not a timeout on the overall request, but a timeout on an individual read/write. If it blocks for that long it would generally indicate something has locked up.